# Efficiently recognize a rectangular shape from a massive array of points

Tags: c#, arrays, shapes, point, lidar

How would you guys go into solving this problem?

I have a series of devices along a straight path.
Let's assume all perfectly aligned with each other.

My application will be built as C# Desktop project with WPF front end and .NET 5 back end.

Since I'll also be implementing historicization of data I'll be implementing also Entity Framework to manage a SQL Server instance.

All these devices are capable of reporting an array of 4000 points.
These points are delivered in polar coordinates, so angle and distance from the device itself.

I have all these points being pooled inside a single array. Depending on the configuration of the deployment, there can be even more then 40'000 points in the array.

I have this array of points all brought back to cartesian coordinates (X, Y) and rototranslated into a single reference plane.

What would be an efficient way of recognizing in this nebula a series of rectangular shapes e determine their size?

I only got as far as this point:

1. Filter isolated points.
2. Filter points outside of possible read area.
3. Use ransac and consensus methods to recognize straight lines.
4. Filter lines shorter then a minimum acceptable value.
5. Cross lines with each other to determine the corners of the objects.

I have a feeling that nowadays there might be a more innovative way of doing this but I'm always so covered in stuff to do that I cannot find the time to solve this bug in my head...

Do you guys have an idea?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Addendum:

The rectangle are NOT GUARANTEED to be perfectly straight or a perfect shape in any way.

This means, the rectangle could be slightly rotated from x axis, or the rectangle could have a narrower head then tail. Within limits of course.

Comment: I guess the best you could hope for, is create a `dictionary<x,y[]>` and `dictionary<y,x[]>` and a series of loops to check for the existence of a valid rectangle. You could use sorted  dictionaries which would make the check faster, though it might not make the process more efficient. I started writing the code for this, however I am going to run out of time before work. Whether its faster than what you have I'm not sure

Comment: this is the code I had, https://dotnetfiddle.net/HDlBkE it may or may not be useful to you or anyone else, and not complete and may have all sorts of issues :)

Comment: Thanks for the support tomorrow morning I'll try *crossfingers* to find time to open it. Thanks for taking the time :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best way to do this would be with a Dictionary, I have chosen a sorted dictionary though you would have to benchmark either approach.

<sub>***Disclaimer**: I have only done minimal testing, it could be completely wrong.*</sub>

**Given**

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToSortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> existing) => new(existing);
}
```

**Implementation**

```
public static IEnumerable<Rectangle> Enumerate(SortedDictionary<int, int[]> xs, SortedDictionary<int, int[]> ys)
{
   // iterate the x dictionary
   foreach (var (x1, value) in xs)
   {
      // get all y values
      foreach (var y1 in value)
      {
         // does the Y dictionary contain the y ?
         if(!ys.TryGetValue(y1, out var x2s)) continue;

         // get all xs where is greater then the original
         foreach (var x2 in x2s.Where(xa => xa > x1))
         {

            // check if x exists in x dictionary
            if (!xs.TryGetValue(x2, out var y2s)) continue;

            foreach (var y2 in y2s.Where(ya => ya >y1))
            {
               if (!ys.ContainsKey(y2)) continue;

               yield return new Rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);

               break;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var points = new Point[]
{
   new(1, 1),
   new(1, 2),
   new(1, 3),
   new(2, 3),
   new(3, 3),
   new(3, 1),
   new(3, 2),
   new(3, 3),
};

var xs = points
   .GroupBy(p => p.X, p => p.Y)
   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToArray())
   .ToSortedDictionary();

var ys = points
   .ToLookup(p => p.Y, p => p.X)
   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToArray())
   .ToSortedDictionary();

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerate(xs, ys)));
```

**Output**

```
{X=1,Y=1,Width=2,Height=2}
{X=1,Y=2,Width=2,Height=1}
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vw5fq9)

## Benchmarks

**Summary**

The speed will depend on how many rectangles you expect to find, in this case I am using a range of 0..10000 x/y. I am sure you can get it faster though. It doesn't quite scale linearly in both memory and speed, however it's definitely not a quadratic time complexity or worse.

Note I have included a crude parallel version, it will run better the more rectangles you expect to find, in this incarnation the parallel version can complete 100,000 points in about 80ms on my system

**Environment**

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=Windows 10.0.19043.1237 (21H1/May2021Update)
Intel Core i7-7700 CPU 3.60GHz (Kaby Lake), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET SDK=5.0.401
  [Host]   : .NET 5.0.10 (5.0.1021.41214), X64 RyuJIT  [AttachedDebugger]
  .NET 5.0 : .NET 5.0.10 (5.0.1021.41214), X64 RyuJIT

Job=.NET 5.0  Runtime=.NET 5.0
```

**Results**

| Method | N | Mean | Error | StdDev | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Single | 100 | 62.02 us | 0.841 us | 0.745 us | 76 KB |
| Para | 100 | 119.63 us | 1.375 us | 1.286 us | 165 KB |
| Single | 1000 | 827.67 us | 16.159 us | 15.870 us | 733 KB |
| Para | 1000 | 652.92 us | 12.901 us | 28.317 us | 959 KB |
| Single | 10000 | 11,761.19 us | 220.978 us | 415.050 us | 5,454 KB |
| Para | 10000 | 7,281.76 us | 148.422 us | 430.598 us | 6,591 KB |
| Single | 100000 | 260,526.78 us | 4,947.544 us | 5,293.817 us | 63,186 KB |
| Para | 100000 | 80,518.47 us | 1,595.902 us | 3,150.154 us | 72,006 KB |
| Single | 1000000 | 23,062,589.42 us | 424,680.649 us | 397,246.542 us | 4,342,997 KB |
| Para | 1000000 | 4,907,088.21 us | 33,959.608 us | 30,104.308 us | 5,127,048 KB |

**Full Test Code**

```
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net50)]
[MemoryDiagnoser()]
public class Points
{

   private Point[] _points;

   [Params(100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000)] public int N;

   [GlobalSetup]
   public void GetPoints()
   {
      var r = new Random(32);
      _points = Enumerable
         .Range(0, N).Select(x =>
            new Point(
               r.Next(10000),
               r.Next(10000)))
         .ToArray();

   }

   public static IEnumerable<Rectangle> Enumerate(SortedDictionary<int, int[]> xs, SortedDictionary<int, int[]> ys)
   {
      // iterate the x dictionary
      foreach (var (x1, value) in xs)
      foreach (var y1 in value) // get all y values
      {
         // does the Y dictionary contain the y ?
         if (!ys.TryGetValue(y1, out var x2s)) continue;

         // get all xs where is greater then the original
         foreach (var x2 in x2s.Where(xa => xa > x1))
         {
            // check if x exists in x dictionary
            if (!xs.TryGetValue(x2, out var y2s)) continue;

            foreach (var y2 in y2s.Where(ya => ya > y1))
            {
               if (!ys.ContainsKey(y2)) continue;
               yield return new Rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
               break;
            }
         }
      }

   }

   public static IEnumerable<Rectangle> EnumerateParallel(SortedDictionary<int, int[]> xs, SortedDictionary<int, int[]> ys)
   {
      IEnumerable<Rectangle> Rectangles(int[] value, int x1)
      {
         foreach (var y1 in value) // get all y values
         {
            // does the Y dictionary contain the y ?
            if (!ys.TryGetValue(y1, out var x2s)) continue;

            // get all xs where is greater then the original
            foreach (var x2 in x2s.Where(xa => xa > x1))
            {
               // check if x exists in x dictionary
               if (!xs.TryGetValue(x2, out var y2s)) continue;

               foreach (var y2 in y2s.Where(ya => ya > y1))
               {
                  if (!ys.ContainsKey(y2)) continue;
                  yield return new Rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
                  break;
               }
            }
         }
      }

      return xs.AsParallel().AsUnordered().SelectMany(x => Rectangles(x.Value, x.Key));

   }
   [Benchmark]
   public Rectangle[] Single()
   {
      var xs = _points
         .GroupBy(p => p.X, p => p.Y)
         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToArray())
         .ToSortedDictionary();

      var ys = _points
         .ToLookup(p => p.Y, p => p.X)
         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToArray())
         .ToSortedDictionary();

      return Enumerate(xs, ys)
         .ToArray();
   }

   
   [Benchmark]
   public Rectangle[] Para()
   {
      var task1 = Task.Run(() => _points
         .GroupBy(p => p.X, p => p.Y)
         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToArray())
         .ToSortedDictionary());

      var task2 = Task.Run(() =>_points
         .ToLookup(p => p.Y, p => p.X)
         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToArray())
         .ToSortedDictionary());

      return EnumerateParallel(task1.Result, task2.Result)
         .ToArray();
   }
}
```

Comment: Wow oh my god I didn't expect to receive such an extensive and complete answer! Thanks a lot sir! I will surely give it a test!